# Plotting semilog plot with pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I am trying to graph frequency response of certain filters.
This is the code I currently have:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[xlabel=Frequency, ylabel=Gain, xmin=1, xmax=20000, ymin=0, ymax=2]

\addplot[domain=1:1e4,color=red] {250000/(x*x + 500*x + 250000)};

\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

What it does is create this:
[image: plot]

Does anyone know why the red line stops at 4 or so, and how to prevent that?

Comment: Hi Orpheon, welcome to the site! Are you perhaps using quite an old version of PGFPlots (the current one is 1.9)? When I try to compile this code, I get an error message that the domain `0:1e4` is unsuitable for logarithmic plots (which is of course true). If I correct the domain (to `1:1e4`, for example), everything works fine.

Comment: First of all, use some xmin>0, like xmin=1.

Comment: Fixed, but the graph still only draws a small part of the entire function.
Also, I am using the default ubuntu package of all Latex packages, not sure how to find out the version of a specific one.

Comment: If you add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` and compile, a list of all packages used with the version number will be added to the `.log` file, near the end.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: With the current version of PGFPlots, it's not necessary to set `xmin` to a value greater than zero: Nonsensical values are automatically disregarded.

Comment: Actually, since xmax=2(10^4), it is precisely where it should be.

Comment: Oh, you mean the red line.  Worked fine when I tried it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the cause of the problem was the calculation involving numbers way above 10^5 which is when the internal calculator starts breaking, and hence pgfplot simply did not draw any points where that happened.

I "solved" it by generating a table externally and loading it, works pretty well for me.

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\caption{2-pole Lowpass filter frequency response}
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=Frequency, ylabel=Gain, xmin=1, xmax=5, ymin=0, ymax=2]

\addplot[mark=none, color=red] file {lowpassfrequencyresponse.dat};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: Your original code works fine for me. This must be a problem with your setup, perhaps an outdated version of PGFplots or TikZ.